# Using Acquia for a production site and running Wordpress concurrently

Tags: 6

I've been building a website for my library in Drupal 6 using the Acquia Installer package on my local machine, a Win7 PC. I'm also going to need to run 2-3 Wordpress blogs alongside Drupal on the same machine, both on my local machine and when everything is migrated to our Server 2008/IIS 7 machine.

Do I need to ditch Acquia Installer now while still developing in order to run WP alongside Drupal? I've thought about installing WAMP alongside Acquia just to run WP on my local machine. But that seems like it would kill my local machine, running two separate installs of Apache, MYSQL, PHP, etc. And Acquia + WAMP probably isn't the smartest way to set up an efficient production environment on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquia Installer is just an *AMP package. It installs standard versions of Apache, MySQL, and PHP, so you can configure Apache for multiple vhosts just as you would on any other machine.

Here's a guide to setting up vhosts on drupal.org http://drupal.org/node/111238

If you are deploying to IIS, I'd suggest at least testing your site locally before you push to live. These links may be of help:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/505/install-drupal-on-iis/
http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

The second is a Microsoft IIS installer with native Drupal support. MS are supporting Drupal as part of their Windows 8 push, so there are more resources around for IIS as a platform than previously.

Answer (score -2):

Thats what I would recommend, actually ditching the Aquila installer and using WAMP locally for both Drupal and Wordpress on different Apache vhosts. Then in production host it on a traditional LAMP server.

The other alternative would be to make your Drupal 7 install a "multisite" with different URLs and settings in /sites//modules etc. and host all the Blogs and the Drupal sites on Drupal, its MORE than capable and the blog modules are all in core default install so you already have everything :)

Comment: jkniep is not asking how to set up multisite Drupal or whether he should switch those Wordpress sites to Drupal or their server to Linux.

Comment: was a mistake. IMHO, i disagree about give -1 when is a mistake. Asking about delete can be an alternative. it's my opinion.